# Export SQL as CVS with Matching ID's

Tags: mysql, wordpress, website

I have an SQL database that I'm exporting as CVS sheets to import into a new WordPress website. CVS sheets to import into a new WordPress website. I downloaded the user.cvs which has the basic user information. I downloaded the user_information.cvs. I can't combine (or merge) the two CVS sheets because they have no common factors. Is there any way I can add a common value to both SQL tables so I can merge they after downloading?

I've been reading tutorials and watching videos for the past week and can't find how to make all the data in the database matching up.

Also, the original website was a php website which can no longer load.

Thank you for your time
Kim

Comment: Can you share example data from your two tables?

Comment: Are you exporting all the WP tables?  Then importing them into an existing WP user?  Can't be done without some code; see if there is a plugin that helps.

Comment: Consider posting your question on the WP site; I doubt if SF is best.